# Should functions that take functions as parameters, also take parameters to those functions as parameters?

Tags: c#, architecture, functional-programming

I often find myself writing functions that look like this because they
allow me to easily mock data access, and still provide a signature that accepts parameters to determine what data to access.

```
public static string GetFormattedRate(
        Func<string, RateType>> getRate,
        string rateKey)
{
    var rate = getRate(rateKey);
    var formattedRate = rate.DollarsPerMonth.ToString("C0");
    return formattedRate;
}
```

Or

```
public static string GetFormattedRate(
        Func<RateType, string> formatRate,
        Func<string, RateType>> getRate,
        string rateKey)
{
    var rate = getRate(rateKey);
    var formattedRate = formatRate(rate);
    return formattedRate;
}
```

Then I use it something like this:

```
using FormatterModule;

public static Main()
{
    var getRate = GetRateFunc(connectionStr);
    var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(getRate, rateType);
    // or alternatively
    var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(getRate, FormatterModule.FormatRate, rateKey);

    System.PrintLn(formattedRate);
}
```

Is this a common practice?  I feel like I should be doing something more like

```
public static string GetFormattedRate(
        Func<RateType> getRate())
{
    var rate = getRate();
    return rate.DollarsPerMonth.ToString("C0");
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work very well because I'd have to make a new function to pass into the method for every rate type.

Sometimes I feel like I should be doing

```
public static string GetFormattedRate(RateType rate)
{
   return rate.DollarsPerMonth.ToString("C0");
}
```

But that seems to take away any fetch and format re-usability.  Whenever I want to fetch and format I have to write two lines, one to fetch and one to format.

What am I missing about functional programming?  Is this the right way to do it, or is there a better pattern that's both easy to maintain and use?

Comment: The DI cancer has spread so far...

Comment: I struggle to see why this structure would be used in the first place.  Surely it's more convenient (and _clear_) for `GetFormattedRate()` to accept the rate to format as a parameter, as opposed to having it accept a function that returns the rate to format as a parameter?

Comment: If you have to pass in a function with arguments (say because you want to set some options in advance, but others have to be computed by the inner function), I would recommend function currying. I have never attempted to do it in C#, but it'S easy in F# and Python and feels perfectly natural.

Comment: A better way is making use of `closures` where you pass the parameter itself to a function, which in return gives you a function referring to that specical parameter. This "configured" function would be passed as a parameter to the function, which uses it.

Comment: I think this is really just the strategy pattern in disguise, instead of passing objects which contain your functionality, you're passing delegates. Although seeing both functional-programming and C# tags simultaneously makes me think I might be misunderstanding completely.

Comment: Related Article on Joel's, by BenjiSmith: [Why I hate frameworks](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12)

Comment: @IdanArye DI cancer?

Comment: @Jules dependency injection cancer

Comment: I like DI, I  think the problem here is just that it would have been better to inject something like a IRateProvider and IRateFormatter, or maybe just a IRateProvider, rather than messing around with Funcs. I don't think strategy pattern is required here.

Comment: This does not appear to be is not the sort of problem function objects were introduced to solve. Function objects are about delayed execution (something is hard to compute or not needed yet, so don't compute until you have to), not throwing function objects in as arguments because you can.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you do this long enough, you'll eventually find yourself writing this function over and over:

```
public static Type3 CombineFunc1AndFunc2(
    Func<Type1, Type2> func1,
    Func<Type2, Type3>> func2,
    Type1 input)
{
    return func2(func1(input))
}
```

Congratulations, you've invented [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Wrapper functions like this don't have much use when they're specialized to one type. However, if you introduce some type variables and omit the input parameter, then your GetFormattedRate definition looks like this:

```
public static Func<A, C> Compose(
    Func<B, C> outer, Func<A, B>> inner)
{
    return (input) => outer(inner(input))
}

var GetFormattedRate = Compose(FormatRate, GetRate);
var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(rateKey);
```

As it stands, what you're doing has little purpose. It's not generic, so you need to duplicate that code all over the place. It overcomplicates your code because now your code has to assemble everything it needs from a thousand tiny functions on its own. Your heart's in the right place though: you just need to get used to using these sorts of generic *higher order functions* to put things together. Or, use a good old fashion lambda to turn `Func<A, B>` and `A` into `Func<B>`.

Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Do repeat yourself if avoiding repeating yourself makes the code worse. Such as if you always write those two lines instead of `FormatRate(GetRate(rateKey))`.

Comment: @immibis I guess the idea is that he'll be able to use `GetFormattedRate` directly from now on.

Comment: I think this is what I'm trying to do here, and I've tried this Compose function before but it seems that I rarely get to use it because my 2nd function often needs more than one parameter.  Perhaps I need to do this in combination with closures for configured functions as mentioned by @thomas-junk

Comment: @rushinge This kind of composition works on the typical FP function which always has a single argument (additional arguments are really functions of their own, think of it like `Func<Func<A, B>, C>`); this means that you only need one Compose function that works for any function. However, you can work with C# functions well enough just using closures - instead of passing `Func<rateKey, rateType>`, you onlry really need `Func<rateType>`, and when passing the func, you build it like `() => GetRate(rateKey)`. The point is that you don't expose the arguments the target function doesn't care about.

Comment: @immibis Yes, the `Compose` function is really only useful if you need to delay the execution of `GetRate` for some reason, such as if you want to pass `Compose(FormatRate, GetRate)` to a function which provides a rate of its own choosing, e.g. to apply it to every element in a list.

Answer (score 105):

There is absolutely no reason to pass a function, and its parameters, only to then call it with those parameters. In fact, in your case you have no reason to pass a function *at all*. The caller might as well just call the function itself and pass the result.

Think about it - instead of using:

```
var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(getRate, rateType);
```

why not simply use:

```
var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(getRate(rateType));
```

?

As well as reducing unnecessary code it also reduces coupling - if you want to change how the rate is fetched (say, if `getRate` now needs two arguments) you don't have to change `GetFormattedRate`.

Likewise, there's no reason to write `GetFormattedRate(formatRate, getRate, rateKey)` instead of writing `formatRate(getRate(rateKey))`.

Don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: In this case you are correct.  But if the inner function were called multiple times, say in a loop or a map function, then the ability to pass in arguments would be useful.  Or use functional composition / currying as proposed in @Jack answer.

Comment: @user949300 maybe, but that's not the OP's use case (and if it was, perhaps it's `formatRate` that should be mapped over the rates that should be formatted).

Comment: @user949300 In that case, one should think about, whether it is right doing it in such a way.

Comment: @user949300 Only if your language does not support closures or when lamdas are a hazzle to type out

Comment: @user949300 Since the question is C#, the API can have a standard function interface, and the user can use a lambda to pass any other required data. e.g. `string GetFormattedRate(Func<Thing, float> getter)` and then `GetFormattedRate(thing => ComplexLogic(thing, also, many, params))`.

Comment: Note that passing a function and its parameters to another function is a *totally valid way* to delay evaluation in a language without lazy semantics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk

Comment: @Bergi, Kroltan: your lambdas are a fine idea.  They are, in effect, functional composition / currying, as suggested in my comment and in Jack's answer.  I guess "lambda" is the trendy terminology nowadays and I should have used that.  :-)

Comment: This decoupling also has the benefit that the formatting function can be used for a completely separate rate computed using totally different arguments, without modifying or re-implementing `GetFormattedRate`. Also, I think `FormatRate` is a better name for the function as implemented in this answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith Passing the function, yes, passing its parameters, only if your language doesn't support closures.

Comment: I think that the x86 emulator that I am using passes function pointers and the parameters to these functions because it is implementing C++ inheritance from scratch in C.

Answer (score 16):

If you absolutely need to pass a function into the function because it passes some extra argument or calls it in a loop then you can instead pass a lambda:

```
public static string GetFormattedRate(
        Func<string> getRate)
{
    var rate = getRate();
    var formattedRate = rate.DollarsPerMonth.ToString("C0");
    return formattedRate;
}

var formattedRate = GetFormattedRate(()=>getRate(rateKey));
```

The lambda will bind the arguments the function doesn't know about and hide that they even exist.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this what you want?

```
class RateFormatter
{
    public abstract RateType GetRate(string rateKey);

    public abstract string FormatRate(RateType rate);

    public string GetFormattedRate(string rateKey)
    {
        var rate = GetRate(rateKey);
        var formattedRate = FormatRate(rate);
        return formattedRate;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rateFormatter = new StandardRateFormatter(connectionStr);
        var formattedRate = rateFormatter.GetFormattedRate(rateKey);

        System.PrintLn(formattedRate);
    }
}
```

If you want a method that can behave in multiple different ways in an object-oriented language such as C#, the usual way to do that is to have the method call an abstract method. If you don't have a specific reason to do it a different way, you should do it that way.

Does this look like a good solution, or are there downsides you're thinking of?

Comment: There are a couple of wonky things in your answer (why is the formatter also getting the rate, if it's just a formatter? You could also remove the `GetFormattedRate` method and just call `IRateFormatter.FormatRate(rate)`). The basic concept however is correct, and I think too OP should implement its code polymorphicaly if he needs multiple formatting methods.